# How to Play HTML5 video and YouTube Video within Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to play html5 video and youtube video within android webview, but can't display video on android webview screen. and play this video.

I have used below code snippet...

layout xml file naming: test.xml contains below code snipet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rltvLayoutTest"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webViewTest" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and Activity Class name: Test.java contains code given below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewTest);


        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new chromeClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://broken-links.com/tests/video/");
    }

    public class chromeClient extends WebChromeClient implements OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener{
        private WebView wv;
        private VideoView mVideoView;
        private LinearLayout mContentView;
        private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
        private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
                wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewTest);
                mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) view;
                mCustomViewCallback = callback;
                mContentView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rltvLayoutTest);
                if (mCustomViewContainer.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                    mVideoView = (VideoView) mCustomViewContainer.getFocusedChild();
                    // frame.removeView(video);
                    mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
                    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                    mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
                    mVideoView.start();

                }
            }
        }

        public void onHideCustomView() {
            if (mVideoView == null)
                return;
            // Hide the custom view.
            mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mVideoView);
            mVideoView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            // Show the content view.
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            onHideCustomView();
            setContentView(mContentView);
        }

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            setContentView(mContentView);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [html5webview](http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/) to solve this problem.Download and put it into your project then you can code just like this.

```
private HTML5WebView mWebView;
String url = "SOMEURL";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
    setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}
```

To make the video rotatable, put android:configChanges="orientation" code into your Activity
for example (Androidmanifest.xml)

```
<activity android:name=".ui.HTML5Activity" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

and override the onConfigurationChanged method.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: this project is based on the minSDKversion. If version is more than 11, it does not work.

Comment: It works. You don't have to put any apk in your project. It is a library. Try searching how to use library in your android project.

Comment: how to use the apk as a library in our project?

Answer (score 0):

you haven't added mCustomViewContainer to your view hierarchy

Comment: I cant get, where i have to add mCustomViewContainer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running it on tablet... you add hardwareaccelerated= true in your manifest file and it will certainly work.. also change the sdk version to 11

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. May help you as well [play html videos](https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/checkout)

Comment: Can't play Youtube video automatically