# Unable to play html5 streaming video in android web view

Tags: android, html, uiwebview

I have bought Foscam Security Camera and I am able to see the JPEG streaming on my MacBook.
But when I open the same link in my phone browser using chrome then it starts downloading something not sure what and in notification menu shows unsuccessful download.

Plus if I open the same link on my Android Firefox browser then I am able to see the video.

I have to create an android application to show the streaming of the video just as it is viewable on laptop browser.

The following is the code I am using:

```
package org.securitycamera;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class SecuritycameraActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
        View inflatedView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.main, null); 

        if (!(inflatedView instanceof FrameLayout))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("inflated view not FrameLayout");
        }
        else
        {
            frameLayout = (FrameLayout)inflatedView;
        }

        setContentView(frameLayout);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());         


        try
        {
           // webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.6/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=");
            webView.loadUrl("http://broken-links.com/tests/video/");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
        VideoView videoView;
        WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
        {
            if (newProgress == 100) 
            { 
                view.loadUrl("javascript:playVideo()");
            }

        }

        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
        {
             if (view instanceof FrameLayout){
                 FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
                 if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView){
                     VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                     frame.removeView(video);
                     setContentView(video);
                     video.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            //Log.i(DVNGActivity.TAG, "LoadData_QRURL --> onCompletion...");
                            mp.stop();
                            setContentView(R.layout.main);
                        }
                    });
                     video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        //  Log.i(DVNGActivity.TAG, "LoadData_QRURL --> onError");
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                     video.start();
                 }
             }

        }

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
        }

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
          // this is needed to release the MediaPlayer and its resources so it can
          // be used again later 
          videoView.stopPlayback();

          // now remove the video and tell the callback to hide the custom view 
          frameLayout.removeView(videoView);
          customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

          finish();
        }

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
        {
            return false; // we did not handle the error - onCompletion will be called
        }
    }
}
```

I followed this [How to Play HTML5 video and YouTube Video within Android WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978961/how-to-play-html5-video-and-youtube-video-within-android-webview), and if instead of playing the video in example I play the video of my security camera i.e.

```
webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.6/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=");
```

I get a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

this sample https://gist.github.com/3718414 has an Android webview wrapper and HTML5 video - it's not as simple as just referencing the URL (if you want the video in the webView) but it's not difficult on ICS and above (ensuring you have hardware acceleration enabled seems to be pretty key)